# Remove duplicate outcomes, when outcomes are strings and not in the same order

Tags: r

I want to create a data frame with the possible outcomes of rolling two dice. The point of this is to run a simulation separately and populate the data frame with the number of outcomes. I wrote the following code to create the data frame:

```
dice1 <- sort(rep(1:6,6))
dice2 <- rep(1:6,6)
dicesum <- dice1 + dice2

df <- data.frame(dice1, dice2, dicesum)

> str(df)
'data.frame':   36 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ dice1  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 ...
 $ dice2  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 1 2 3 4 ...
 $ dicesum: int  2 3 4 5 6 7 3 4 5 6 ...

> head(df)
  dice1 dice2 dicesum
1     1     1       2
2     1     2       3
3     1     3       4
4     1     4       5
5     1     5       6
6     1     6       7
```

I first considered creating pairs, such as (1,6), ... , (6,6), to remove duplicates when (dice1, dice2) == (dice2, dice1). However, the outcome is not desirable because both both instances of the pairs are removed (e.g. (1,6) and (6,1)) and doubles are also removed (e.g. (2,2), (6,6)).

Note: I consider a (1,6) and a (6,1) a duplicate outcome. 
Question:**What is the best way to remove duplicate outcomes from my data frame?**

Comment: Is `(1,6)` a character string?

Comment: Question corrected. @PoGibas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the data structure you have after the edit to the question, I believe the following can do it.

```
inx <- duplicated(t(apply(df, 1, sort)))
df[!inx, ]
```

The one-liner of the code above is obvious.

Comment: Loved your solution. Simple and elegant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating the dataframes yourself for the simulations, another way to not have duplicates is to avoid generating them at all.

For example, you can use the `combinations` function from the `gtools` package to generate the required dataframe:

```r
df <- as.data.frame(gtools::combinations(6, 2, repeats.allowed=TRUE))
names(df) <- c("dice1", "dice2")
df$dicesum <- df$dice1 + df$dice2
df
#>    dice1 dice2 dicesum
#> 1      1     1       2
#> 2      1     2       3
#> 3      1     3       4
#> 4      1     4       5
#> 5      1     5       6
#> 6      1     6       7
#> 7      2     2       4
#> 8      2     3       5
#> 9      2     4       6
#> 10     2     5       7
#> 11     2     6       8
#> 12     3     3       6
#> 13     3     4       7
#> 14     3     5       8
#> 15     3     6       9
#> 16     4     4       8
#> 17     4     5       9
#> 18     4     6      10
#> 19     5     5      10
#> 20     5     6      11
#> 21     6     6      12
```

Comment: Quite surprisingly, a function which seems to be missing in base R, indeed.

Comment: @Uwe - actually `gtools::combinations` will do it in a single step (I finally remembered where I'd seen it before!). See edited answer

Comment: Excellent, great find. Unfortunately, I can not upvote a second time.

Answer (score 1):

The approach used [in the answer of markdly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46532720/3817004) ("*another way to not have duplicates is to avoid generating them at all*") can be implemented as a *non-equi self join* using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
(DT<- data.table(1:6))[DT, on = .(V1 >= V1), .(dice1 = i.V1, dice2 = x.V1)][
  , dicesum := dice1 + dice2][]
```

> ```
>     dice1 dice2 dicesum
>  1:     1     1       2
>  2:     1     2       3
>  3:     1     3       4
>  4:     1     4       5
>  5:     1     5       6
>  6:     1     6       7
>  7:     2     2       4
>  8:     2     3       5
>  9:     2     4       6
> 10:     2     5       7
> 11:     2     6       8
> 12:     3     3       6
> 13:     3     4       7
> 14:     3     5       8
> 15:     3     6       9
> 16:     4     4       8
> 17:     4     5       9
> 18:     4     6      10
> 19:     5     5      10
> 20:     5     6      11
> 21:     6     6      12
>     dice1 dice2 dicesum
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data_frame(pairs = list(c(1,2), c(2,1), c(2,2)))
```

### `df_sum` is your input data frame:

> df_sum <- df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(sum = sum(pairs)) %>% ungroup()

```
> df_sum %>% glimpse()
Observations: 3
Variables: 2
$ pairs <list> [<1, 2>, <2, 1>, <2, 2>]
$ sum   <dbl> 3, 3, 4
```

### To remove duplicates in the `pairs` list-column:

> res <- df_sum %>% rowwise() %>$% mutate(pairs = list(sort(pairs))) %>% unique()

```
res %>% glimpse()
Observations: 2
Variables: 2
$ pairs <list> [<1, 2>, <2, 2>]
$ sum   <dbl> 3, 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in base R (with the original question in mind)

data:

```
structure(list(pairs = c("(1,1)", "(1,2)", "(1,3)", "(1,4)", 
"(1,5)", "(1,6)", "(2,1)", "(2,2)", "(2,3)", "(2,4)", "(2,5)", 
"(2,6)", "(3,1)", "(3,2)", "(3,3)", "(3,4)", "(3,5)", "(3,6)", 
"(4,1)", "(4,2)", "(4,3)", "(4,4)", "(4,5)", "(4,6)", "(5,1)", 
"(5,2)", "(5,3)", "(5,4)", "(5,5)", "(5,6)", "(6,1)", "(6,2)", 
"(6,3)", "(6,4)", "(6,5)", "(6,6)"), sum = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L)), .Names = c("pairs", "sum"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36"), class = "data.frame")
```

name of the data frame is `dups`

remove the parenthesis and the comma, split the string to characters, convert to numeric and sort

```
b = lapply(strsplit(gsub("\\((\\d),(\\d)\\)", "\\1\\2", dups$pairs), ""), function(x) sort(as.numeric(x)))
```

collapse to character vectors

```
b = lapply(b, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ""))
```

duplicated entries

```
b = duplicated(unlist(b))
```

show all but the duplicated elements

```
dups[!b,]
#output:  
  pairs sum
1  (1,1)   2
2  (1,2)   3
3  (1,3)   4
4  (1,4)   5
5  (1,5)   6
6  (1,6)   7
8  (2,2)   4
9  (2,3)   5
10 (2,4)   6
11 (2,5)   7
12 (2,6)   8
15 (3,3)   6
16 (3,4)   7
17 (3,5)   8
18 (3,6)   9
22 (4,4)   8
23 (4,5)   9
24 (4,6)  10
29 (5,5)  10
30 (5,6)  11
36 (6,6)  12
```